# Rclone installation in docker on heroku with telegram bot [Help]

Tags: docker, heroku, bots, telegram, rclone

I want to install rclone on a docker image in heroku to able to use Rclone with python telegram bot
I made a heroku.yml file

```
build:
  docker:
    worker: Dockerfile
run:
  worker: bash start.sh
```

And start.sh as

```
python3 -m bot
```

And Dockerfile as

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN docker pull rclone/rclone:latest
RUN docker run rclone/rclone:latest version
RUN chmod 777 /usr/src/app
RUN apt -qq update
RUN apt -qq install -y python3 python3-pip locales
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

CMD ["bash","start.sh"]
```

I get error `The command '/bin/sh -c docker pull rclone/rclone:latest' returned a non-zero code: 127` in the git bash CLI

What Am I doing wrong? Or what is the procedure?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can’t usually run `docker` commands from inside Docker space, and especially not from within a Dockerfile.  What are those two lines trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to install rclone so that I can execute shell commands with the help of telegram bot PS- I tried RUN apt install rclone --classic and it made it work! But I have 2 files inside a folder named bot, they are not getting pushed to heroku and hence heroku app crashes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

WORKDIR /app
# line number 12 - 15 in your Dockerfile
RUN echo "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/environment
RUN echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/environment
RUN more "/etc/environment"

RUN apt-get update
#RUN apt-get upgrade -y
#RUN apt-get dist-upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install curl htop git zip nano ncdu build-essential chrpath libssl-dev libxft-dev pkg-config glib2.0-dev libexpat1-dev gobject-introspection python-gi-dev apt-transport-https libgirepository1.0-dev libtiff5-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libgsf-1-dev fail2ban nginx -y

# Install Rclone
RUN curl -sL https://rclone.org/install.sh | bash
RUN rclone version

# Cleanup
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get autoremove -y
```

> ###### Based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720784/how-to-install-latest-node-inside-a-docker-container/1064507#1064507)

You can try this, also don't try to use docker commands inside a Dockerfile.

Comment: I worked around and used rclone binary

Comment: Owh u meant, Heoku Rclone shell Bot? I was als having this problem and I tried with binary it doesn't worked for me, so I used this method...